# What is the "Browse" application for?

Tags: gimp, desktop-apps

I see a program in the applications overview in Ubuntu 17.10 named "Browse".

What is this application for, and is it a default application for Ubuntu 17.10?

Clicking on the launcher does nothing.

**Additional Info**

I *believe* its launcher is `/usr/share/applications/org.laptop.WebActivity.activity.desktop`.

If I try to run the the `Exec=` command from the `.desktop` file on the command line, I get the following errors:

```
cd /usr/share/sugar/activities/Browse.activity

sugar-activity webactivity.WebActivity -s

1517966060.546701 ERROR root: SUGAR_VERSION env variable not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sugar-activity", line 220, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/sugar-activity", line 215, in main
    instance = create_activity_instance(activity_constructor, activity_handle)
  File "/usr/bin/sugar-activity", line 48, in create_activity_instance
    activity = constructor(handle)
  File "/usr/share/sugar/activities/Browse.activity/webactivity.py", line 156, in __init__
    activity.Activity.__init__(self, handle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugar3/activity/activity.py", line 422, in __init__
    self._jobject = self._initialize_journal_object()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugar3/activity/activity.py", line 476, in _initialize_journal_object
    datastore.write(jobject)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugar3/datastore/datastore.py", line 381, in write
    transfer_ownership)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugar3/datastore/datastore.py", line 331, in _create_ds_entry
    object_id = _get_data_store().create(dbus.Dictionary(properties), filename,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sugar3/datastore/datastore.py", line 50, in _get_data_store
    DS_DBUS_PATH),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.laptop.sugar.DataStore was not provided by any .service files
1517966060.613335 WARNING root: DSObject was deleted without cleaning up first. Call DSObject.destroy() before disposing it.
```

Here is the output of my logs files...

```
zgrep sugar /var/log/dpkg.log*

/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 install libsugarext0:amd64 <none> 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status half-installed libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 install gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 <none> 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status half-installed gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 install python-sugar3:all <none> 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status half-installed python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 install sugar-browse-activity:all <none> 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status half-installed sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status half-installed sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:11:22 status unpacked sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:01 configure libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:01 status unpacked libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:01 status half-configured libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:01 status installed libsugarext0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:02 configure gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:02 status unpacked gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:02 status half-configured gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:02 status installed gir1.2-sugarext-1.0:amd64 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 configure python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status unpacked python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status half-configured python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status installed python-sugar3:all 0.110.0-4
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 configure sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1 <none>
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status unpacked sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status half-configured sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2018-01-27 00:12:18 status installed sugar-browse-activity:all 201.2-1
```

Comment: Searching http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.manifest doesn't find `sugar`. Can you try `zgrep sugar /var/log/dpkg.log*` assuming that you have all the dpkg logs (even the archived ones since installation).

Comment: @DKBose, I executed `zgrep sugar /var/log/dpkg.log*`, but I did not get results.  I know I do not have all the log files, since installation.

Comment: @DKBose, I found the log files on another computer and have updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Impish 21.10 and still have this question/problem.

Many years and many releases later, I found the answer...

**"Browse" Application**

The purpose of the "Browse" application is to allow Gimp to display help information.

**Explanation**

When I installed `gimp`, I would also install `gimp-help-en`.

- Package `gimp-help-en` requires package `gimp-helpbrowser`. (See [gimp-help-en](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gimp-help-en)).
- However `gimp-helpbrowser` is not available in Ubuntu 17.10 and above, so the alternative package that satisfies this dependency is `www-browser`.
- `www-browser` is a virtual package, and there are 19 packages that provide [www-browser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/www-browser).
- The package `sugar-browse-activity` is one of these 19 packages. See [sugar-browse-activity](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sugar-browse-activity). (In my case, `apt` choose to install `sugar-browse-activity` instead of one of the other 19 applications, such as `firefox`, because I installed the `firefox` deb package *after* installing `gimp-help-en`).

Thus, `sugar-browse-activity` is responsible for installing the file, `/usr/share/applications/org.laptop.WebActivity.activity.desktop` , which is supposed to launch the "Browser" application. ([See the list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/sugar-browse-activity/filelist)).

**Resolution**

I tested Gimp 2.10.24 in Ubuntu 21.10, but this probably applies to other versions of Ubuntu as well.

Using help simply launches my default browser (Firefox) and displays the contents in the web browser.

Therefore, avoid installing the "Browse" application, install one of the 19 packages that provide  `www-browser` before installing `gimp-help-en`. See [sugar-browse-activity](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/sugar-browse-activity). Note that [firefox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/firefox) is listed as one of those applications.

**Ubuntu 21.10**

In Ubuntu 21.10, `wslu` (for [Windows 10 Linux Subsystem](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/wslu)) is another package that provides `www-browser` (see [sugar-browse-activity for Impish](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/www-browser)).

So, there is a possibility you might get `wslu` installed on your Ubuntu 21.10 system if you try to install `gimp-help-en`.

Again, the solution to avoid installing `wslu` or the "Browse" application, is to install one of the 24 packages in Impish that provide  `www-browser` before installing `gimp-help-en`. See [sugar-browse-activity](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/www-browser). Note that [firefox](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/firefox) is listed as one of those applications.